# How to post a file with telnet or a raw socket?

Tags: python, sockets, file-upload, http-post

I'm trying to post a file within a raw socket, I read the RFC, and I think I actually tested a lot of options but I'm now stuck.

By the way, I know I could use pycurl, httplib, etc., but I really want to do it manualy.

Here the request:

```
POST /upload.php?foo=bar HTTP/1.0
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=9afb0c26-7adf-11e0-b167-1c6f65955350

--9afb0c26-7adf-11e0-b167-1c6f65955350
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="image.png"
Content-Type: image/png

#PNG

IHD&#   )IDA##x##       D
                         [##
###b######j
5#r#`IEND#B`#
--9afb0c26-7adf-11e0-b167-1c6f65955350--
```

All those lines are from an array joins :

```
"\n".join(lines)
```

I tried both with \n & \r\n

And I send to CRLF at the end.

I read my images like this:

```
f = open(file, 'rb')
file_content = ''
while True:
    chunck = f.read(1024)
    file_content += chunck
    if len(chunck) == 0:
        break;

lines.append(file_content)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I wish you luck with this; at first I was tempted to try to find the problem, but on second thought this is such a crazy idea.  I can't imagine why you want to do it the hard way (what kind of http error handling do you have???) when it is so easy with `urllib2`, `twisted` or `scrapy`

Comment: That's not a [raw socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_socket).

Answer (score 1):

Shouldnt there be a 'Content-Length' in the part-headers?

Comment: The RFC states it's optional, however, I tried to define one but with no success

Comment: What exactly happens? As in, what does the server side say? Some server-side implementations 'REQUIRE' the content-length, so that they know how much is coming.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already figured out the header you will use, I recommend putting it into
a multiline string like this:

```
# An infinitely clever way to make \r\n\r\n at end of header, although technically
# inferior to just going rnrn = '\r\n\r\n' tho.  Shut up...
rnrn = '\n'.join('\r\r\r')[:4]

# remember that each line in an http header must be terminated with \r\n.
# Since multiline strings already add a \n terminator at the end of each line, 
# all that is needed is \r at the end of each line.

header = """POST /upload.php?foo=bar HTTP/1.0\r
Host: localhost\r
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=9afb0c26-7adf-11e0-b167-1c6f65955350\r
--9afb0c26-7adf-11e0-b167-1c6f65955350\r
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="image.png"\r
Content-Type: image/png\r
#PNG\r
IHD&#   )IDA##x##       D\r
                     [##\r
###b######j\r
5#r#`IEND#B`#\r
--9afb0c26-7adf-11e0-b167-1c6f65955350--"""+rnrn

HOST = '' #your hostname here
PORT = 0 #your port here

from socket import *
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

s.send(header)
return_data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()

print('Got back: ', return_data)
```

And that's pretty much it.  The real zen of python is that the actual coding
part is really simple, the real challenge is what you're coding with it.

I am writing a HTTP program with raw sockets myself.  It will be an xchat script
that uses babelfish.yahoo.com to translate messages on IRC from foreign speakers.

Comment: [george grounds again] you might actually want to - instead of how i just put the code in with the header, actually go """+imgdata+"""... so that it will be whatever your image generator from file thing came up with.

Answer (score 0):

Every line of the header must be terminated with CRLF. See here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5

Comment: I tried both with \r\n & \n, but I always get "partially upload file"